# Python3 - Issues with "subprocess.call()" function

Tags: python, tkinter, subprocess

my software uses the `subprocess.call([sys.executable, SCRIPT_NAME]` instruction in order to open others kind of scripts specified by the user using a GUI (Tkinter). I have two issue with this instruction:

1. the "command line" scripts start and close themeselves quicly and it means that the user can't interact with them. it's a weird behaviour because in all of them there is an input instruction, so they should wait an input by the user before to close themeselves. how can I solve this issue?
2. the "GUI" scripts instead, start without any kind of issue, but their "life", let me say, put in stuck the main script (it uses Tkinter). in this case I can interact with the second script but not with the main one. how can I call my other scripts with the `subprocess.call()` function whithout put in stuck the main one? from my point of view this issue happens because the second script is a part of the same process of the main one and in this case Tkinter has to wait. if we open the others scripts using different processes for all of them the main script would be free to live its life independently of the others. but how can I do it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `subprocess.call` is blocking, which I think might explain 2), as for 1), it's a subprocess, how do you expect your user to interface with the command line?

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time, and please try to include a [mcve] showing what you're doing.

Comment: Use `subprocess.Popen()` for item 2.

Comment: @acw1668: `Popen` solves the second issue!!! but not the first one.. if I use the `subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, SCRIPT_NAME])` command in my interpreter, my "cli scripts" run as I axpect, but they run in the same console where I'm. so how can I run them in a new console with `Popen`? maybe it could solve the issue, I don't know..

Comment: For item 1, if in Windows, use `subprocess.call(['start', sys.executable, SCRIPT_NAME], shell=True)`. If in Linux, use one of the terminal program (for example, `gnome-terminal`) to execute the required command.

Comment: @acw1668: the `subprocess.call(['start', sys.executable, SCRIPT_NAME], shell=True)` solves both issues!! can you explain me the command? if I had to use `os.system` module I would use `os.system("start "+SCRIPT_NAME)`. it works but, it shows me the console on the screen for some milliseconds, and I don't like it. it is the main reason behind my choise to use the "subprocess" module, but the syntax it's quite complicate.. why doesn't a command like `subprocess.call(['start', SCRIPT_NAME])` work?

Comment: `start` is an internal command in Windows, so it need to be executed by a command shell.  That's why `shell=True` is required.  Or you can use `subprocess.call(['cmd', '/c', 'start', sys.executable, SCRIPT_NAME])`.

Comment: For item 1, you can also use `subprocess.call([sys.executable, SCRIPT_NAME], creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)`